# Unusual behavior of ARM assembly program

Tags: assembly, arm, undefined-behavior

I have been writing JIT ARM compiler for simple expressions. My Just-in-time compiler is given addresses to the functions and variables that will be used in the expression and the expression itself. And it generates ARM code that computes the expression.

This is the output of my compiler for the expression `inc(1) + 1`:

```
start:
    push    {r4}        //saving r4
 
    ldr     r0, [pc]    //writing the constant into r0
    b       skip0       //skipping data line
    .word   0x1
 
skip0:
    push    {r0}        //saving the constant
 
 
    pop     {r0}        //fucntion time. Let's pop the argument
    ldr     r4, [pc]    //Let's get function address
    b       skip1       //skipping data line
    .word   0x13050
 
skip1:
    bx      r4          //jumping to function
    push    {r0}        //saving the output of it
 
 
    ldr     r0, [pc]    //writing the constant into r0
    b       skip2       //skipping data line
    .word   0x1
 
skip2:
    push    {r0}        //saving the constant
    pop     {r0-r1}     //getting function result and the constant

    add     r0, r1, r0  //adding them to each other
    push    {r0}        //saving the result
 
    pop     {r0}        //work done, popping the result to r0 in order to return it
    pop     {r4}        //placing r4 back
    bx      lr
```

`inc(x)` is an external function that just returns `++x`. `0x13050` is the address of the function at the moment of execution.

The problem is - the output is 2, but it must be 3. I can't find the bug, could you help me?

Fun fact: if I change `bx` to `blx` I get a segfault

Comment: Most ARM CPUs support `movk`/`movt` to construct a 32-byte value in 2 instructions.  Probably better to use that instead of spending code size jumping over a `.word` that you load.  (And then it's an easy optimization to your JITter to notice constants that can be encoded with one regular `mov`.)

Comment: I would certainly disagree with "most arm cpus"....we need to know what core this is (thus what architecture thus what instruction set).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the final line: `blx` overwrites `lr`
And since you didn't preserve `lr` in the beginning, `bx lr` at the end would cause a branch back to the line `push {r0}` after `blx r4`, causing an infinite loop.
And since you pop one more time than push each iteration, the stack pointer will point on an invalid address some time => segfault

With `bx r4` the sub function `inc(x)` won't return to your function, but to the caller function with the return value 2 in addition to INCORRECT stack pointer.

```
start:
    push    {r4, lr}        //saving r4 AND lr
 
    ldr     r0, [pc]    //writing the constant into r0
    b       skip0       //skipping data line
    .word   0x1
 
skip0:
    push    {r0}        //saving the constant
 
 
    pop     {r0}        //fucntion time. Let's pop the argument
    ldr     r4, [pc]    //Let's get function address
    b       skip1       //skipping data line
    .word   0x13050
 
skip1:
    blx      r4          //jumping to function
    push    {r0}        //saving the output of it
 
 
    ldr     r0, [pc]    //writing the constant into r0
    b       skip2       //skipping data line
    .word   0x1
 
skip2:
    push    {r0}        //saving the constant
    pop     {r0-r1}     //getting function result and the constant

    add     r0, r1, r0  //adding them to each other
    push    {r0}        //saving the result
 
    pop     {r0}        //work done, popping the result to r0 in order to return it
    pop     {r4, pc}        //placing r4 back AND return
```